# Do particles act like waves on large scales?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality

I've seen illustrations of particles being particles and then becoming waves momentarily on impact before going back to being particles. But I picture it as particles behaving like waves on the grand scale. Are the particles and waves measured on the same scale? Basically what I'm trying to say is, is saying lightwave particle duality anything like saying $H_{2}O$ molecule water wave duality? Or is that just the classical interpretation?

Comment: "Particles" are secondary phenomena of quantum fields. One can explain particle-like behavior as the consequence of quantum fields, but not the other way around. Because there is no consistent explanation of quantum fields in the particle picture, one shouldn't think of the world as consisting of particles, at all.  Think of all particle-like objects as localized states of fields that span the entire universe.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I do remember this being in a lecture. You essentially just clarified something i wasn't paying much attention to at the time, haha. Thank you.

Comment: @CuriousOne Can you elaborate on this point: "no consistent explanation of quantum fields in the particle picture"  In condensed matter we construct field theories from single particle states on lattices?

Comment: @Shane: Where are the particles in condensed matter, again? Condensed matter systems usually consist of atoms or molecules. Can you put a mean field theory on top of that that is valid in a tiny temperature range? Sure. It's also very quickly overwhelmed by thermodynamics.

Comment: @CuriousOne: I was thinking about how Bloch waves are used when deriving the Hubbard model.  I'm not so concerned about the temperature range in which the theory is consistent. Just that field theories can be developed using single particle theories in a mathematically consistent way. Or were you saying experimentally consistent?

Comment: @Shane: Where are the particles in that model? An electron is not a particle, not even in the Schroedinger equation. Look, I am not trying to be difficult here, but the particle picture has been dead for 80 years. It hasn't worked back then, it doesn't work today. Just let it go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Particles do not become waves, nor waves waves become particles, nor any other thing in the between.

The terminology of being a particle or a wave is, in the classical literature, addressed to the solutions of the Newton's equations and the D'Alambert equation, respectively, but nevertheless has no direct experimental meaning, even in the classical picture (without going to quantum mechanics). In fact, keep in mind that the equations are only a way to predict and describe quantities that can be measured in a laboratory, and the latter ones are the characteristics that really matter. For example, although counterintuitive, you may think that a ball is a particle because you somehow see it, but what actually happens is that your eyes absorb the photons scattered by the ball: in this respect a ball in no more of a particle than anything else you can scatter photons on. Likewise when you measure energy, momentum and so forth.

Equations in quantum mechanics and quantum field theory tend to be D'Alambert like, therefore people tended to use the unfortunate terminology of *particles behaving like waves* (or anything else of that sort). However, the mathematical description is nothing but a framework and a language that allows you to predict the quantities that you will eventually measure in a laboratory. In particular, the observables that one deals with are most of the times scattering amplitudes and transmissions coefficients. Such quantities naturally arise out of an elegant description that makes use of fields as operators on some Fock spaces acting on elements of a system; in order to obtain finite quantities many mathematical constructions are necessary and sometimes people tend to address physical meaning to each of those steps, although they have none, being only a language that allows us to describe and precisely predict new outcomes.

In this respect, many equivalent formulations of the same theory may arise, some making use of this and some of that other description and formalism; as such, every interpretation of the mathematics is equally correct (or incorrect). When in a laboratory, you only measure the outcomes, that is, a number (energy, momentum, scattering amplitudes), however this number has been generated. The bottom line is that the terminology used in these contexts is sometimes misleading because it tries to make sense of a mathematical formulation, whilst from the point of view of the physics the only true quantities are the ones you can directly measure, no matter the name you want to give the underlying formalism.

Comment: Nice answer. I personally tend to think somewhat in the opposite direction. The equations are for me the approximate "reality" for experimental "reality", whilst the purpose of words is to convey a "poetic" or "evocative" analogy that one thinks might evoke the kind of structure in the equations, which in turn organize our experimental knowledge. So, for me, if a phenomenon fulfils D'Alembert's equation, call it a "wave" if you like (one can't really get "wavier" than a solution of the D'Alembert equation!), but do not expect to make inferences from words alone: they are simply analogies.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance: I think we are simply not paying enough attention to the fact that it's called "quantum mechanics" and not "particle" or "wave mechanics". Neither are we talking about "quantum wave theory", but we are calling it "quantum field theory". This naming convention seems so trivial that as soon as "particle" and "wave" enter the discussion, the purposeful naming of the theory and its constituents are completely forgotten. Gennaro got it: the only measurable entities are outcomes. The attempt to derive further meaning from those has taken on rather quixotic proportion.

Comment: I think we are simply not paying enough attention to the fact that it's called "quantum mechanics": I like that one: the number of questions on this site like the current question show that huge numbers of students are wasting huge amounts of their intellectual energy, and time, thinking that "is it a wave or a particle?" is a deep question. It was certainly conveyed as such to me as an undergrad. My own user name is derived from the notion that my evolutionary history began and ended in the Neogene wet savannas of East Africa: my words and intuitive thoughts therefore are constrained ....

Comment: .... wholly to the description of patterns we met there. So we should never expect everything we see in physics to conform to these patterns or analogies, but somehow our students are still expecting "sloshy wave" and "dollop of stuff" to yield insight.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance: Thankfully I was warned by my high school physics teacher not to fall for this trap. He gave me a clean logical out: always remember the fallacy of the excluded third hypothesis. That, by the way, is my basic rule for debugging: never exclude the hypothesis that the experimental physicist in front of the apparatus is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

> I've seen illustrations of particles being particles and then becoming waves momentarily on impact before going back to being particles.

This is  a misleading description of what happens at the microscopic level, the underlying level of nature, where quantum mechanics reigns.

When talking of particles with dimensions smaller than nanometers ($10^{-9}~\text{m}$) one does not really have particles, but quantum mechanical entities. The dual nature misrepresented in the sentence above is described by the mathematics of quantum mechanics. On impact and towards impacting, a wave function describes the behaviour, a solution of the quantum mechanical boundary problem for the scattering. This wavefunction squared gives the probability of the scattering happening. It is this probability that has a wave nature, i.e. many instances have to be gathered of the impact and then the wave nature can be seen in the "probability of impact" distribution.

Take an electron and send it to pass through [two slits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment):

[image: doubleslit]

One at a time a random hit is seen in the top frames. After an accumulation an interference pattern appears. This is the wave nature of the electron, the dots are the particle nature since they can be imagined as coming from a small billiard ball. But particles at that size are quantum mechanical entities, not classical particles.

> But I picture it as particles behaving like waves on the grand scale.

No. The quantum mechanical scale is controlled by the size of [$\hbar$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant) , a tiny number . It is only in very special set-ups that the quantum mechanical nature may appear in synergy. For example lasers, or superconductivity.

> Are the particles and waves measured on the same scale?

No. The electron in the example above is supposed to be a point particle and experimentally  a very tiny limit exists. The wave like undulations of the  probability distribution appear at a few microns or so.

> Basically what I'm trying to say is, is saying lightwave particle duality anything like saying H2O molecule water wave duality? Or is that just the classical interpretation?

The $H_2 O$ is an underlying framework for the appearance of the energy wave on water. As explained above the wave nature of elementary particles is not a matter wave or an energy wave , but a wave in the probability of interaction pattern.

Comment: Thumbs up, except that the tiny dots in the image above are not supposed to be particles. They are tiny dots and that will show up nicely in a microscope if you care to use one on a film or phosphor screen. It's a psychological phenomenon that drives people from extrapolating from a tiny, but on the order of the actual quantum phenomenon monstrously large tiny dot to a "particle". As for the most direct effect of quantum mechanics, no need to go to lasers or superconductors. All matter is a direct consequence. Pick up a stone... it wouldn't exist without QM.

Comment: @CuriousOne well, when one finds a hole in the breast of a victim one extrapolates to a bullet. The hole is an air space surrounded by quantum mechanical agglomeration of atoms, the bullet dito. except it fits a classical trajectory calculable with classical equations. The same is true for the traces of an electron, they fit a classical trajecory, that is why one uses the 'particle' name. it is again the duck syndrome.

Comment: Wait... didn't you just show the very experiment that disproves the classical trajectory hypothesis for electrons????

Comment: @CuriousOne   I showed that an accumulation of trajectories has a different behavior that makes me decide it is not a classical particle, as I would think at first, since it does not have a consistent trajectory. The first impression is of a classical trajectory but it is wrong. The dots look like bullet holes but their accumulation differs from the bullet expectations

Comment: You showed me an accumulation of dots. Why you would talk about trajectories when there are nothing but dots only the gods of poor logical reasoning know. And that's all this is: a logical fallacy that once we have two types of behavior in nature every new phenomenon somehow has to fit into that 1-step-2step scheme. There is no rule in logic like that.

Comment: @CuriousOne In my father's house, which no longer exists, there were holes on the wooden door from fragments of  a mortar bomb that fell on the house across the street. The bomb had come from three kilometers away on the hill where the red rebels were. We neither saw the rebels shooting, nor saw ( just heard ) the mortar falling, nevertheless, from the holes we could extrapolate the trajectories, even though we did not use equations. I still have a fragment in my 'jewelry" box , which I dug out of the door when I grew up.( that bomb happened in 1944, in athens, greece

Comment: In the two slit experiment, I know electrons leave in a trajectory from the source, and if no obstacle is on the way they will leave a dot on the screen. If there were no trajectories for elementary particles we would not have accelerators. The new thing is the probabilistic nature of the trajectories which needs a new definition/theoretical_model, and leads to quantum mechanics.

Comment: About bomb fragments: And that is exactly the fallacy, that everything in life is like everything else in life. :-) What you know about electrons is, of course, 100% wrong. You think you know that they have trajectories, but you have never seen one. Not once. It's all an extrapolation from misunderstood facts of classical physics. The problem is that those who walk around touting classical trajectories for quantum mechanical objects have never asked themselves about the difference between what they know from an observation and what they think they know based on analogy.

Comment: @CuriousOne  What  I really know from observations is impulses that reach my brain , analogues of what I build up as the world around me, and as everybody else does. Which becomes metaphysical because maybe everything , including classical and quantum mechanics and you  is a dream I am dreaming. That is where your reasoning takes us. Humans are pattern recognition animals and they organize the patterns they see and generate language labels on similar patterns. That is all. For me it is illogical to think that a mathematical model is what nature is. I use different models to describe different

Comment: frameworks , and use language and mathematics to describe observations in order to communicate. I know that a classical trajectory sometimes fits the behavior of electrons, and sometimes it does not. This tells me the classical model is inadequate and the new probabilistic quantum mechanical model is  what describes the electron behavior globally. In certain boundary conditions the behavior  is like a classical trajectory because it fits classical equations, in certain others it goes off and that is why elementary particles are "quantum mechanical entities", not particles.

Comment: I am not a solipsist. To me that's just a psychological problem that usually disappears with the end of puberty. I don't know if you are aware of this, or not, but science and especially physics start with an act of trust: you trust that nature will answer the same question the same way every time you ask. Trust, OTOH, is not faith, it has to be earned, and nature earns that trust pretty well. That is how adults overcome the solipsist delusion that they are living in a bad dream (which childhood can be).

Comment: What this does not do for us is to give us the intellectual ability to follow Mark Twain's great phrase: "It ain't what you don't know that gets you into trouble. It's what you know for sure that just ain't so.". THAT is what makes quantum mechanics so hard to "grock" for many. They can't let go of assumptions they made while looking at classical systems (even though even those assumptions are technically often enough wrong, they just don't hurt as much in classical mechanics).

Comment: Well if you go to the underlying interactions for observations, the undelying interactions are in the brain of the individual. It has no meaning to go to the underlying  quantum mechanical interactions that within errors describe the quantum mechanical trajectory of an electron, any more than the wavefunctions for  the circle trajectories that fit the electrons and positrons circling a collider and fitted with classical trajectories. There the economic logical imo decision is that they show the particle aspect/(envelope?).

Comment: Classical trajectories never fit the behavior of electrons, they merely fit the behavior of measurements in a classical regime. That, too, is something that we have to learn to differentiate.

Comment: OK I know your  pov and you know mine. Good night.